# Read Zabbix events to Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, zabbix

I am trying to integrate Zabbix with Elastic Search through logstash and further generate dashboard on Kibana. Now there are many links which suggest it is possible to monitor elasticsearch through Zabbix but not the other way around.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/zabbix

Now I got one link which suggests zabbix servers can be monitored. I followed the same but not success

http://philippe.lewin.me/2014/10/06/send-zabbix-events-to-logstash/

I need some help to understand the possibilities and probable some workarounds.

Comment: I think you need a [custom alert script](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/notifications/media/script) that either calls logstash or directly sends data to ElasticSearch. Did you have a look at that?

Comment: No I have not looked into it. But also I am not getting any reference to start from

Answer (score 0):

OP, are you still having the same problem? I also am looking for a way to send my zabbix snmp event data to Elastic Search.

True, the plugins out there are helping the other way around though

I will try phillipe's way later, if all else fail, probably i will try to migrate specific table(s) with another tools directly like Logstash for example